# ¿Cómo envío correo electrónico en ASP.NET con un servidor empresarial?

Tags: asp.net

Este es el código que estoy intentando utilizar para enviar un correo electrónico:

```
public class Email
{
    MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

    public bool enviarCorreo(string to, string from, string mensaje, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            m.From = new MailAddress(from);
            m.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
            m.Body = mensaje;
            smtp.Host = ("smtp.live.com");
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential (from, password);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(m);
            return true;
            //m.IsBodyHtml = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Carlos. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías aclarar cuál es la pregunta? Es decir, publicaste el código, pero ¿funciona? Y si no funciona ¿da algún error? ¿Se conecta al servidor y tenés acceso al mismo? ¿Cuál es la respuesta del servidor?

Comment: bienvenido al sitio, ¿Te parece si agregas el error que te lanza ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se exactamente cual es el problema en tu caso. Me parece que omitir el asunto puede ser la causa del problema. Te dejo un ejemplo que a mi me funciona para enviar desde una web, solo que lo mando con gmail y de remitente fijo, espero te ayude para encontrar el error.

En el web.config:

```
  <system.net>
     <mailSettings>
          <smtp from="tucorreo-desalida@tudominio.com">
            <network host="smtp.live.com" password="tu contraseña" port="587" userName="tu usuario"/>
          </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

En tu metodo:

```
public bool enviarCorreo(string to, string mensaje, string password){

        var correo = new MailMessage();
        correo.To.Add(to);              
        correo.Subject = "Asunto";
        correo.Body = mensaje;

        correo.IsBodyHtml = true;
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        LblEnviado.Text

        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(correo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LblEnviado.Text = ex.ToString();
        }

       LblEnviado.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: GRACIAS!! ya me funcionó!! Saludos!!!

Comment: Si te ayudo la respuesta te agradecería la marcaras como valida o al menos le dieras un voto a favor.